# Where can I ask a question about upgrading Windows 7 computers to Windows 10 over the network?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where can I ask the following question?

> I work in an IT department and we are searching for a way to update all of our Windows 7 computers to Windows 10 without bringing them in and PXE booting them one by one. Is there an easy to do this without doing them one at a time?

Comment: Read the info of the [site-recommendation tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/site-recommendation/info) you’ve just used. _“After looking through the site list, https://stackexchange.com/sites, don't know where to ask your question on the Stack Exchange Network? […] Please phrase your question explicitly as a site recommendation, or it might be closed as blatantly off-topic.”_ Have you looked at the [site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites)?

Comment: Yes I have and I couldn't find the appropriate place

Comment: We get a lot of people who ask blatantly off-topic questions here and attempt to get their answer *here on this site*. As such, we expect site recommendations to be clearly phrased as such, with the intended question in quote formatting. I've edited your question with the expected format.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few sites all related to Computer issues so it can be hard to find the right site.

I suggest https://serverfault.com/ which lists the topics as:

> Q&A for system and network administrators

And [their help centre](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) expands on this:

> ## What topics can I ask about here?
>
> Server Fault is for questions
> **about managing information technology systems in a business
> environment**.
>
> If your question is about:
>
> - managing the hardware or software of servers, workstations, storage or
> - networks tools used for administering, monitoring, or automating these
> - deployment to and management of third-party provided information
>   technology platforms
>
> and is not about:
>
> - consumer workstations or networking (which belong on our sister site,
>   Super User)
> - working with a service provider's management interface,
>   such as cPanel product, service, or learning material recommendations
> - product licensing inquiries or legal advice career, salary, personnel,
> - employment, or formal education unauthorized use or misuse of IT
>   systems
>
> then you’re in the right place to ask your question!